# SQL Server Invalid Object Name for renamed table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am running the following query (auto-generated by SSMS):

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
  FROM [GestionePrestazioni].[dbo].[Prestazioni]
```

which raises the following error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name dbo.VociRicevuta
```

Database table VociRicevuta was recently renamed to RicevutaVoci, by an Entity Framework 6 migration. This table has a ForeignKey referencing the PrimaryKey of table Prestazioni.

EDIT: A view from SSMS of the two tables:
[image]

I searched StackOverflow but it seems no one has my problem. I have no idea how to solve this. Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: Aren't there also foreign keys on `Prestazioni` that refer to `VociRicevuta`?

Comment: I [can't actually replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d69a75273a1e325fb0c0e4273f44685) this issue with T-SQL alone. Are you sure that Entity Framework renamed the table, and didn't `DROP` it and then `CREATE` a new one? Otherwise, is, perhaps `Prestazioni` actually a `VIEW` or similar object?

Comment: @GSerg no, see my edit.

Comment: @Larnu No, data is still there. Prestazioni is a table as you can see from my edit

Comment: The screenshot is not really helpful. Please post the DDL for both tables.

Comment: Perhaps you have a computed column using a scalar function? An image of the object explorer doesn't help us. Post the **full** DDL of both objects. That means the tables, it's constraints, and the definition of any objects used in computed columns. WE need an [mre] here.

Comment: @Larnu you're right! One column of the table is computed, using a Stored Procedure, and that Stored Procedure references the old table! I will update the question. But now the problem is "cannot ALTER stored procedure because it is refecenced by table Prestazioni"

Comment: Computed Columns can't reference Stored Procedures... I ***assume*** it's a scalar function. You'll have to `DROP` the column(s) that reference the function, then `ALTER` said function, and then `ADD` the column back to your table(s).

Comment: You're right. It's a scalar function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larnu guessed right: The problem was that a column of my table was a Computed Column referencing a Scalar Function, which involved table VociRicevute.

I will now fix that Scalar Function. I will delete the computed column, alter the function, and re-add the column.

Thanks @Larnu !